# how can I fix this error: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

i have the code saying:

```
def averaged_slope_intercept(mage, lines, line=None):
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)

    for line in lines:
        line.reshape(4)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
        parameters = np.polyfit((x1,x2),(y1,y2), 1)
        print(parameters)
        slope = parameters[0]
        intercept = parameters[1]
        if slope < 0:
            left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
        else:
            right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    print(left_fit)
    print(right_fit)
    left_fit_avarage = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    right_fit_avarage = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    print(left_fit_avarage, "left")
    print(right_fit_avarage, "right")
    left_line = make_coordinates(mage, left_fit_average)
    right_line = make_coordinates(mage, right_fit_average)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])
```

but I keep getting this error:
: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1) 
at the line:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)

the lesson is @
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLTLtUVuuy4

Comment: `reshape()` returns a `numpy` array, not 4 values.

Comment: You can adjust the lines as `x1, y1, x2, y2 = *line.reshape(4)` to deconstruct the array to assign values.

Comment: What does `line` or `lines` look like?  That fact that it has a `reshape` method means it's a numpy array, but what's the `dtype` and `shape`?

Answer (score 0):

[`reshape(n)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) returns an numpy array as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505623/how-can-i-fix-this-error-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-4-got-1#comment105183715_59505623) mentioned, which is a single value, but with 4 items. You can fix this by [unpacking the sequence with `*`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) and perform a [sequence assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
def averaged_slope_intercept(mage, lines, line=None):
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []
    #x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)                 # Removed

    for line in lines:
        #line.reshape(4)                              # Removed
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = *line.reshape(4)             # Updated
        parameters = np.polyfit((x1,x2),(y1,y2), 1)
        print(parameters)
        slope = parameters[0]
        intercept = parameters[1]
        if slope < 0:
            left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
        else:
            right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    print(left_fit)
    print(right_fit)
    left_fit_avarage = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    right_fit_avarage = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    print(left_fit_avarage, "left")
    print(right_fit_avarage, "right")
    left_line = make_coordinates(mage, left_fit_average)
    right_line = make_coordinates(mage, right_fit_average)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])
```

Comment: If the array shape is right, you whouldn't need the `*` unpacking.  `a,b,c,d = np.ones((4,3))` works just fine.  An array is iterable in the first dimension.  We need to know more about `line`.

Comment: the main body of the program is segmented into called functions with: lines =  cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, 2,  np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]),  minLineLength=40,  maxLineGap=5) defining the lines variable

Comment: @MNFsoft, I realize your code wasn't semantically correct, not sure how the incoming `line` parameter would help your algorithm.